# Check if two sets have a non-empty intersection

Tags: julia

I wrote a function `intersects` that *efficiently* checks wether two sets have a non-empty intersection (at least, more efficient than checking the size of their intersection).

It works well, but now I would like to specialize this function for the type `DataStructures.IntSet` from the DataStructures library. I wrote the function below, which works, but is a bit messy.

As you can see, when the attribute `inverse` is `true`, I have to negate the current chunk. In an attempt to simplify the code, I wrote the function `intersects2` which does the same work but without the need of multiples if/else.

But this code appears to be less efficient than the first one. I'm not sure, but I think the problem is that each call to `op_u` or `op_v` copy the parameter, as shown in the output below.

How can I rewrite this function such that it does not make any copy (ie. no allocation) and without several imbricated if/else? The full code, benchmarks and results can be found below.

```
using Random
using DataStructures
using BenchmarkTools

elems = [randstring(8) for i in 1:10000]
ii = rand(1:10000, 3000)
jj = rand(1:10000, 3000)


x1 = Set(elems[ii])
y1 = Set(elems[jj])

x2 = Set(ii)
y2 = Set(jj)

x3 = DataStructures.IntSet(ii)
y3 = DataStructures.IntSet(jj)

function intersects(u, v)
    for x in u
        if x in v
            return true
        end
    end
    false
end

function intersects(u::DataStructures.IntSet, v::DataStructures.IntSet)
    ch_u, ch_v = u.bits.chunks, v.bits.chunks
    for i in 1:length(ch_u)
        if u.inverse
            if v.inverse
                if ~ch_u[i] & ~ch_v[i] > 0
                    return true
                end
            else
                if ~ch_u[i] & ch_v[i] > 0
                    return true
                end
            end
        else
            if v.inverse
                if ch_u[i] & ~ch_v[i] > 0
                    return true
                end
            else
                if ch_u[i] & ch_v[i] > 0
                    return true
                end
            end
        end
    end
    false
end

function intersects2(u::DataStructures.IntSet, v::DataStructures.IntSet)
    op_u = if u.inverse x->~x else x->x end
    op_v = if v.inverse x->~x else x->x end

    ch_u, ch_v = u.bits.chunks, v.bits.chunks
    for i in 1:length(ch_u)
        if op_u(ch_u[i]) & op_v(ch_v[i]) > 0
            return true
        end
    end
    false
end


println("Set{String}")
@btime intersects($x1, $y1)

println("Set{Int}")
@btime intersects($x2, $y2)

println("IntSet")
@btime intersects($x3, $y3)
@btime intersects2($x3, $y3)
```

```
Set{String}
  190.163 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
Set{Int}
  17.935 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
IntSet
  7.099 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
  90.000 ns (5 allocations: 80 bytes)
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but you could make intersect much faster in the worst case by making sure to iterate over the smaller of the 2 collections.

Comment: I already tried this, but it appears that, in the case of IntSet, getting the length is a costly operation since it requires to compute the sum over the bitset. Though, you're right for the other types of set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overhead you are seeing is likely due to function call overhead: `op_u` is not being inlined.

This version inlines correctly and has the same performance as `intersects`:

```
julia> function intersects2(u::DataStructures.IntSet, v::DataStructures.IntSet)
           op_u(x) = u.inverse ? ~x : x
           op_v(x) = v.inverse ? ~x : x

           ch_u, ch_v = u.bits.chunks, v.bits.chunks
           for i in 1:length(ch_u)
               if op_u(ch_u[i]) & op_v(ch_v[i]) > 0
                   return true
               end
           end
           false
       end
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. The problem was that the compile couldn't inline `op_u` because it couldn't guess in advance which function should be called. This way, the function is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could have avoided the nesting also with something like this, this is also a bit faster than your `intersects(u::DataStructures.IntSet, v::DataStructures.IntSet)` method, because of `@inbounds`:

```
function intersects4(u::DataStructures.IntSet, v::DataStructures.IntSet)
    ch_u, ch_v = u.bits.chunks, v.bits.chunks
    for i in eachindex(length(ch_u) > length(ch_v) ? ch_u : ch_v)
        @inbounds if (u.inverse && v.inverse && ~ch_u[i] & ~ch_v[i] > 0) ||
           (u.inverse && ~ch_u[i] & ch_v[i] > 0) ||
           (v.inverse && ch_u[i] & ~ch_v[i] > 0) ||
           (ch_u[i] & ch_v[i] > 0) 
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end
```

> Are you sure there can not be a `BoundsError` if `ch_u`'s lenght is larger than `ch_v`'s and the function happens to run the whole loop? I did `for i in eachindex(length(ch_u) > length(ch_v) ? ch_u : ch_v)` just in case, because I haven't tested your function thoroughly.

Great answer by [@David Varela](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60244502/2374329) (I'll call his function `intersects3`), you can get even a bit faster than `intersect4` above if you make sure there will be no `BoundsError` and use `@inbounds`, like this:

```
function intersects5(u::DataStructures.IntSet, v::DataStructures.IntSet)
    op_u(x) = u.inverse ? ~x : x
    op_v(x) = v.inverse ? ~x : x

    ch_u, ch_v = u.bits.chunks, v.bits.chunks
    for i in eachindex(length(ch_u) > length(ch_v) ? ch_u : ch_v)
        @inbounds if op_u(ch_u[i]) & op_v(ch_v[i]) > 0
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end
```

---

```
julia> begin
           @btime intersects($x3, $y3)   # nested ifs and bound checks
           @btime intersects2($x3, $y3)  # with non inline-able ops
           @btime intersects3($x3, $y3)  # David's improvement
           @btime intersects4($x3, $y3)  # without ifs and with @inbounds
           @btime intersects5($x3, $y3)  # David's improvement with @inbounds
       end
7.184 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
87.633 ns (5 allocations: 80 bytes)
6.500 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
3.763 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
3.079 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Also in your code:

```
op_u = if u.inverse x -> ~x else x -> x end
```

You could have also done:

```
op_u = u.inverse ? (~) : identity
```

As `~` operator is just a function and an `identity` function already exists, anyway David's answer is better (because this won't inline either) and `intersects5` is the fastest and more succinct of all, just wanted to mention it though.

Comment: Yes you're right, my function can fail if `u` is larger than `v`... I'd like to avoid checking the length of both `u` and `v` since it is a costly operation on IntSet, but maybe it's not possible. Thank you for your answer, I don't know what `@inbounds` does so I'll check it out.

Comment: My bad, you are checking the length of `u.bits.chunks`, not `u` This is actually a cheap operation.